# Persistence and Repositories

Tags: domain-driven-design

I've had a look around at different examples online.  I've seen written in a lot of places that repositories are only used in DDD for the persistence of aggregate roots.  Yet on DDDSample.Net, there seems to be repositories in the persistence layer for persisting non-aggregate single entities.

This is what I expected to find, so am I right in thinking that repositories are not only reserved in DDD for only persisting aggregate roots?

Cheers,
Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repositories in domain-driven design are about aggregates. Entities are accessed via their aggregate root. There is also Fowler's definition of the [respository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html), which is about "domain objects".

Comment: That's the phrase I keep hearing.  If I have a single entity that isn't part of an aggregate, does this point to problems in my design, should I see this single entity as an aggregate root (with no children) or do I persist it some other way?

Comment: From a DDD perspective that entity is an aggregate root.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, that marries both opinions I'm seeing and the code examples together.  Cheers!